# onProgressUpdate not updating values in android

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

I have an async task which is executed on file download, the progress update works quite fine for progress bar but it doesn't work (app crashes) if i use that values[0] for textview to display progress, i am not able to understand why..

```
@Override
protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values) {
    super.onProgressUpdate(values);
    Log.v("Progress ", Integer.toString(values[0]));
    pbar.setProgress(values[0]);
    // tmin and tmax are texview, on uncommenting app crashes.
    //tmin.setText((values[0].toString()));
    //tmax.setText((Integer.toString(lengthOfFile)));
}
```

Comment: Use `adb logcat`, DDMS, or the LogCat view in Eclipse to examine LogCat and look at the stack trace associated with your crash.

Comment: Please provide the log cat. BTW for noew try this tmin.setText((Integer.toString(values[0])));

Comment: what are you download in AsyncTask??

Answer (score 0):

what is the exception that caused the crash? please look at the logcat view on eclipse .

if it's a null pointer exception , don't forget to set the value of the textViews (depends on what you did , but probably you need to use findViewById) before creating and calling the asyncTask .

Comment: the textview goes like 1% 2% 3% but then crashes...the logcat is showing nothing...may be because its running so fast when downloading the content.

Comment: please put more of the relevant code . i can't see anything problematic with the current one.

Answer (score 0):

This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3028306/download-a-file-with-android-and-showing-the-progress-in-a-progressdialog) gives you a batter code and good explanation after applying this code if does't work then you have to define length in your server side for that file.